# TinyMCE invalid nested list markup

Tags: tinymce

Today I upgraded Wordpress to 3.2.1 and noticed that the nested list markup seems to be invalid.

This is the code it's producing:

```
<ul>
  <li>parent list item 1</li>
<ul>
  <li>child list item 1</li>
</ul>
  <li>parent list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Instead it should look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>parent list item 1
    <ul>
      <li>child list item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>parent list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Anybody else having this problem or have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncheck "WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically"

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ordered-list-nesting-in-the-wysiwyg-editor